# Sharing complex objects in python using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

**Problem:**
   Parallelizing a CPU intensive task among available cores, the function being parallelized requires complex objects to work on (read-only), each object has list/tuples/dictionaries of other objects as attributes.

**Hurdles:**
  Using multiprocessing, can spawn parallel processes , but they are 100x slower than the single process version, which I feel is due to serialization/copying of the objects required.

**Questions:**
   What should be the proper way to share complex objects among processes , using Queue seems to be counter intuitive as locks/semaphores would come into picture , also I am  not sure whether I would be able to put complex objects inside it.

Not sure of using multiprocessing Array/Value as they seem to be made for native C types.

If I want to go ahead with remote manager implementation, should all the objects required for my module be created inside the manager process only , or can they be assigned to a manager proxy class/classes ?
E.g:

```
manager_obj = Some_Manager.Object_Class_Name(already_existing_object)
```

Also, in Linux copy-on-write did not work for me, I can still see lot of memory being consumed by the processes forked.

Comment: We will probably need to see some code to answer this question appropriately. "the function being parallelized requires complex objects to work on (read-only), each object has list/tuples/dictionaries of other objects as attributes." if they are read-only, then create them before you do any multiprocess work, then it is just a fork on each process.

Comment: All the read only objects were created before forking new processes ..but as I have mentioned in the post, it did not help and I could see all the processes working with roughly the same memory which is approx 120 MBs.